# HTML5 session storage on restore browser session in Firefox

Tags: html, session, firefox, storage

I am seeing strange behaviour when using session storage on my current site in Firefox.

When a user navigates to the site a session storage value is set like so:

```
sessionStorage.setItem(cacheKey, cacheValue);
```

Then i perform a check to see whether the session key has a certain value on subsequent pages on the site.  If so then i run a function, if not then don't.

However, if a user has the 'Restore session' feature in Firefox turned on, the browser seems to store the session key but not the value (empty string).  I perform a check on the value as which subsequently fails because the value is now null or an empty string.

Is there a more robust way of dealing with this behaviour?

Comment: Unsure what the desired functionality of sessionStorage is in this case is but I would probably just treat it as a new session if the value is `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unexpected behaviour like this, I would treat the "recovered" session as a new session if it is not persisting the value.

A simple null check on the value should suffice.

```
if (window.sessionStorage.getItem(cacheKey) === null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(cacheKey, cacheValue);
}
```

I feel that if in the future the value is persisted you would probably want to keep the existing value.